# How to add a web server to an existing long-running Python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, webserver, python-multithreading

I have a long-running Python program that is periodically performing work. I have a requirement for it to also host a web server so that it can serve metrics and other admin capabilities. I'd like to use Flask as the web framework, although this isn't a deal-breaker - I only need to route a few URLs. **Is there a suitable web server that I can host on a background thread?**

I suppose the solution I'm looking for is akin to Golang's `net/http` web server wherein I can host and start/stop it on its own goroutine.

I have got this working using Flask's inbuilt development server but [its documentation advises](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/deploying/) that this should not be used in production. [Likewise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) for Python's `http.server`.

Edit: I have also tried using `Gunicorn`'s `BaseApplication` on a background thread but, under-the-hood, it listens for OS signals which isn't allowed on anything but the main Python interpreter thread. Ditto for `twisted`.

Answer (score 1):

Flask is not suitable for production because it doesn't scale well...
however you can use a framework like Bottle.

Comment: So I've got this working. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Interestingly, out-of-the-box, it uses `wsgiref.simple_server` which is based on `http.server`. Does that mean it also is not suitable for production?